# What form does the Law of Total Probability take if the partition you use is generated by the random variable Y?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, random-variables, integer-partitions

The Law of Iterated Expection Looks like E{E(X|Y)} when the partition you use is generated by the random variable Y rather than Ω. What happens when you use such a partition on the Law of Total probability?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Same thing: $$\Pr(A) = \operatorname E(\Pr(A\mid Y)). \tag 1$$

For each value $y$ that the random variable $Y$ can take, you have a conditional probability $\Pr(A\mid Y=y),$ and that is a function of the value $y,$ so call that $h(y).$ Then $h(Y)$ is a random variable an is what we call $\Pr(A\mid Y).$

Notice that $(1)$ is a consequence of the law of total expectation: It is just the case where $X$ is the indicator random variable of the event $A,$ i.e.
$$
X = \begin{cases}
1 & \text{if } A \\ 0 & \text{if not } A.
\end{cases}
$$
Then you have $\operatorname E(X) = \Pr(A)$ and $\operatorname E(X\mid Y) = \Pr(A\mid Y).$

Comment: Thank you! I got as far as P(A)= ∑P(A|Y=yi)pY(yi) over yi in curly Y but wasn't sure where to take it next.

Comment: @Matt : I'm glad it helped. You can "accept" the answer if it's appropriate.

Comment: Oh yes, I'm still new to this site I'm afraid.